# In Python, why is y**2 sometimes incorrect when y is a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, exponent

First I compute a square in the IDLE shell of Python 3.12.0:

```
>>> x = 123456
>>> x**2
15241383936
```

This agrees with my TI-89.  Now I compute what I would think would be the same square using numpy arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y = np.array([x])
>>> ysqr = y**2
array([-1938485248])
>>> ysqr[0]  
-1938485248
```

What is going on here?  Why aren't `x**2` and `ysqr[0]` equal?

---

**A solution:**  Just to note for those using Python for scientific computing, we can make `ysqr[0]` equal to `x**2` in the above example by changing x to a float:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y = np.array([float(x)])
>>> ysqr = y**2
array([1.52413839e+10])
>>> ysqr[0]  
15241383936.0
```

Comment: It's a numeric overflow (on 32-bit signed integer). Try `123456**2 % 2**32 - 2**32` to replicate this overflow. In python integers are "infinite", limited only by your memory and time. In `numpy` you got a 32-bit integer. You can use `np.int64` type to get more, but it will still overflow for sufficiently large numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is of type int, which is unbounded in Python and thus x**2, which is also an int can reach arbitrarily high value.

However, `y` is a numpy array with a specific data type. We can observe its data type with `print(y.dtype)` and see that it's `np.int32`. Using `np.iinfo(np.int32)`, we can see the following: `iinfo(min=-2147483648, max=2147483647, dtype=int32)`.

Since 15241383936 is larger than the max value of int32, it overflows and starts counting up from -2147483648. In fact, it is so large, it cycles through to 2147483647 and does this multiple times until it finally lands on -1938485248